# How to loop over loadmore button while scraping in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

'''I've tried this code to loop over loadmore button to load all the products in webpage. But I'm facing error "Button is not clickable at point". Actually after loading all the products in webpage the loadmore button is not disappearing so my loop  doesn't end. Button is still on the page after loading products but not clickable. That's why it gives me error. Please help me with my code.'''

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time
url = 'https://mamaearth.in/shop'
driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path=r"Enter your path")
driver.get(url)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="Button__MinimalButton-sc-wiqi81-0 Button__Styled-sc-wiqi81-1 cLpIaN"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
j = 0
try:
    while button.is_displayed():
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        prodd = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("uniquewhite")
        newlist = prodd[j:]
        for productt in newlist:
            link = productt.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
            print(link)
        j = len(prodd)+1
        time.sleep(5)
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    pass
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all the product links from that page using requests module. The following implementation will help you fetch product links from those pages that show up when you click on the load more button.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://mamaearth.in/product/{}'
link = 'https://mmrth-nd-api.honasa-production.net/v1/products/shopAllProducts'

params = {
    'pagenumber': 1,
    'pagesize': '20',
    'categoryId': '-1'
}
headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://mamaearth.in/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    while True:
        res = s.get(link,params=params)
        try:
            container = res.json()['response']['list']['entities']['products']
        except KeyError:
            break
            
        for val in container.values():
            print(base.format(val['slug']))

        params['pagenumber']+=1
```

Output (truncated):

```
https://mamaearth.in/product/eggplex-conditioner-with-egg-protein-collagen-for-strength-shine-250-ml
https://mamaearth.in/product/eggplex-shampoo-with-egg-protein-collagen-for-strength-and-shine-250-ml
https://mamaearth.in/product/ubtan-face-wash-with-turmeric-saffron-for-tan-removal-150-ml
https://mamaearth.in/product/vitamin-c-face-wash-with-vitamin-c-and-turmeric-for-skin-illumination-250ml-2
https://mamaearth.in/product/skin-illuminate-sunscreen-gel-spf-50-with-vitamin-c-turmeric-for-uva-b-protection-50-g
https://mamaearth.in/product/vitamin-c-foaming-face-wash-combo-pack-with-refill-150ml-150ml
https://mamaearth.in/product/sunscreen-body-lotion-spf-30-300-ml-vitamin-c
https://mamaearth.in/product/sunscreen-body-lotion-spf-30-300-ml-ubtan
https://mamaearth.in/product/sunscreen-body-lotion-spf-30-300-ml-aloe-vera
```

Comment: You are doing with api link and json data. I want the solution using beautiful soup object by using the base url. Thanks anyways.. @SIM

Comment: Thanks for your code but I'm still facing some errors on this code. I've posted a separate question also.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add check

```
if newList:
    for productt in ...
else:
    break
```

so if no new entries appear after clicking LoadMore button loop breaks

Comment: Yes this if else condition works but now how to call the product information i.e., name, price, etc. Thanks btw @JaSON

Comment: @AbhishekSingh try `name = productt.find_element_by_class_name('title').text` and `price = productt.find_element_by_class_name('price').text`